# Get query result by using Cast and Convert function in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to map a `varchar` column to a `datetime`. To do that I need to filter out values which can't be converted to `datetime`:

```
SELECT myfield 
FROM my_table
WHERE (SELECT convert(varchar(10), cast(myfield as datetime), 112) ) = 0
```

I'm getting this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? If it's 2014+, you can try `TRY_PARSE`.

Comment: @Mubeen  show us your myfield data

Comment: its cause for your data on myfield, also remove SELECT from Where clause

Comment: to zack's point...if its older...you can do a regex test first...should likely help

Comment: @Mubeen  show us your myfield data then only i can help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT myfield FROM my_table
WHERE isDate(myField)=1
```

Comment: Well, isdate () will check if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value. But the OP mentioned he just want to check 'datetime'.

Comment: `SELECT my_field, * 
From my_table
Where my_field NOT LIKE '[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
AND isdate(my_field) = 0` work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can use try_cast instead of 'cast' if you use SQL Server 2012 above:

```
SELECT myfield FROM my_table
WHERE try_cast(myfield as datetime) is not null
```

Edit:
Removed the select in the where clause.

Comment: This is the preferred method.